# How to get CryptoJS.SHA256 output as same in android

Tags: javascript, android

I am facing a problem with the hash code.

My javascript file is below as I get the hash code by choosing a file from PC is different with my android app.

```
enter code here

    var html5 = window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob;
    $('#wait').hide();

var handleFileSelect = function(f) {
if (!html5) {
  return;
}
explain.html(translate('Loading document...'));
var output = '';
output = translate('Preparing to hash ') + escape(f.name) + ' (' + (f.type || translate('n/a')) + ') - ' + f.size + translate(' bytes, last modified: ') + (f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate
  .toLocaleDateString() : translate('n/a')) + '';

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
  var data = e.target.result;  

  bar.width(0 + '%');
  bar.addClass('bar-success');
  explain.html(translate('Now hashing... ') + translate('Initializing'));
  setTimeout(function() {
    CryptoJS.SHA256(data, crypto_callback, crypto_finish); 
  }, 200);
};
```

and for Android, using code:

```
    public static String computeHash(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    digest.reset();
    try{
        digest.update(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] byteData = digest.digest();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++){
        sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Please help me out that how I can get the same javascript output in my android app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    public static String getSHA(final String ca) {
    MessageDigest md;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(Base64.decode(ca.getBytes()));

        byte byteData[] = md.digest();

        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte aByteData : byteData) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xff & aByteData);
            if (hex.length() == 1) hexString.append('0');
            hexString.append(hex);
        }
        return  hexString.toString().replaceAll("..(?!$)", "$0:").toUpperCase();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

I had similar problem and this was my solution. If there is still some differences, please put an example to check it out.

Comment: You should not expect that you will get full solution. It is part of code that do this job. You have to add 
    implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.54.0.0'
    implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.54.0.0'
to gradle, and change replaceAll to fit to your requirements

Comment: md.update(Base64.decode(ca.getBytes())); cannot resole decode(ca.getBytes()) and also its giving me output like F0:E2:24:D5:G7:3D etc which is not an acceptable output. In javascript the output is c0c39041d9d292486719e59c59a40469f9caff214395ee6ac503f3f4b5ba61af for "Preparing to hash class%206.jpg (image/jpeg) - 6244 bytes, last modified: n/a" please check it again

Comment: @lkazuchi thanks but now it gives me an error and logcat shows "Caused by: org.spongycastle.util.encoders.DecoderException: unable to decode base64 data: invalid characters encountered in base64 data"

Comment: @PardeepSinghYou have to check if your data is prepared correctly, maybe in a process of receiving data, you got some extra values. It fails in decode, that means is something wrong with data. OFC you can replace Base64 with other parser if it gives you proper value.

Comment: @lkazuchi ok i have changed Base64 with android.util.Base64, it works but the output getting is not the same.

Comment: @PardeepSingh Show me correct result and what you got

Comment: @lkazuchi ok 6791cabb6a23d6........65bd2 output m gettingin android but the real output  is c0c39041d9d292486719e59c59a40469f9caff214395ee6ac503f3f4b5ba61af